# How can I move a dynamixel AX-12A motor with a python script?

Tags: python, dynamixel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to move two dynamixel ax-12a motors, one as pan and the other as tilt.
Writing the comands in the shell works fine e.g.
rostopic pub -1 /pan_controller/command std_msgs/Float64 -- 1.5

Now I want to move them by writing a python srcipt but I don't know which command I need to use.
Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224535/how-can-i-move-a-dynamixel-ax-12a-motor-with-a-python-script?/) by [jaron](https://answers.ros.org/users/25666/jaron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just publish on /pan_controller/command messages of type std_msgs/Float64. [Here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(python))'s how to.

Line 7 would look like:

```
pub = rospy.Publisher('/pan_controller/command', Float64, queue_size=10)
```

and 13 like:

```
pub.publish(1.5)
```

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2016-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jaron](https://answers.ros.org/users/25666/jaron/) on 2016-01-24**:
Thank you :) That's what I also found out...